# outputManifest to s3 bucket error : No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, s3distcp

When I use s3-dist-cp in emr jobs to copy files from source s3 to destination s3 with outputManifest argument, the manifest file was written to the destination s3 bucket as well. In theory I should be able to use this manifest file as the previousManifest file the next time to avoid reloading existing files. However, I wonder the correct way to add it to the --previousManifest argument as I've tried s3://, s3a://, and s3n://, and I always got "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Please show us full commands end-to-end and what you've tried with the error, clearly formatted. How are you passing the args? `--previousManifest` does support `s3://`

Comment: Yes, here is an example: 
s3-dist-cp --src s3://<mysourcebucket>/<msourcefolder>/ --dest s3://<mytargetbucket>/<mytargetfolder>/ --outputManifest /tmp/manifest.gz --previousManifest s3://<mytargetbucket>/<mytargetfolder>/manifest.gz. Without the previousManifest the manifest file was copied successfully to the target folder, along with all other files in the source folder. I'd like to use that manifest file in the target folder the next time I run the emr job so it won't repeat copying the existing files again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, can you please update your question to reflect the above commands as well as the full output as text?

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it is some IAM permission issue I have to resolve in order to read the manifest file. Thanks for your help!